# use python to modify json file

Tags: python, json

Hi I have a json file look like this.

```
{
 a : {
       b:"b_value",
       c:"c_value"
     }
}
```

I want to read the json file and modify using python so the file content will be like this

```
{
 a : {
       x:{
          b:"b_value",
          c:"c_value"
         }

     }
}
```

Please help thank you all.

Comment: That does not look like valid JSON

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

1. read the json into a dictionary:

```
import json
with open("json_file.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

2. create your desired structure using `data`:

```
manipulated_data = {"a" : { "x": data["a"] } }
```

3. write your `manipulated_data` into your file:

```
with open("json_file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(f, manipulated_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i need.

Comment: Happy to help :)